# How to create modem gateway by SMSLib using USB?

Tags: java, com, usb, smslib

I want to create a modem gateway by SMSLib using a USB connection, i know that there is no a direct way to do that as SMSLib supports only the ip and serial connections :

```
SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway(id, comPort, baudRate, manufacturer, model)
```

but is there is a possibility to define the comPort when connectiong the device using USB?if yes then how ? and if no then how can i create a virtual com port by reference to the USB port,note that i tried to check the properties of the USB connection through the device manager but didn't find any com port definitions:

[image]

Comment: Normally an USB modem will provide an emulated serial port and that port will be shown by Windows as COMx, it's highly unusual that you can't find that port.  What modem are you using?

Comment: HP 655 laptop, i think ZTE modem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager > Ports. You will find the new COM(?) port there.